# How to reproduce this shape with CSS?

Tags: geometry, polygon, css-shapes, shapes

[Shape to reproduce with CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53fuI.jpg)

Not found [here](https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/) :(

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is not a standard shape, if you want the shape just for display, then the easiest way would be to create a vector image of the shape that you want and import it into your page. If this doesn't work, then there are few different ways of generating irregular shapes.

Have a look at [this](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2018/11/29/an-introduction-to-css-shapes/) article, it has some useful information towards the end of how you can achieve that.